# Converting service written in python to an executable

Tags: python, dll

I have written a windows service in python. When I run the service through command line, using the commands

```
python service.py install
python service.py start
```

it runs perfectly.
 Now I want to convert it into an executable. I used py2exe and ran the following command

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

but as soon as it reaches the following line, the app crashes.

**copy dlls**

```
    copying C:\Python27\w9xpopen.exe -> C:\True copy\dist  
    copying C:\Python27\python27.dll -> C:\True copy\dist  
    setting sys.winver for 'C:\True copy\dist\python27.dll' to 'py2exe'  
    copying C:\Python27\pywintypes27.dll -> C:\True copy\dist  
    copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\run_w.exe -> C:\True copy\dist\service.exe
```

Could somebody tell why and how to solve it?

Comment: How does that app crash?  Please show the complete error message output - everything.

Comment: Try removing the space in the path name. Use `C:\Truecopy\dist` instead of `C:\True copy\dist`